# Oracle Audit: Why Logons are less than 0.1% of logoffs?

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i, audit

I see the following quantities of logins versus logoffs vs logoffs by cleanup in a database:

```
SQL> select action_name, count(*) qty
from Dba_audit_session
group by action_name
order by 1;  2    3    4

ACTION_NAME                        QTY
--------------------------- ----------
LOGOFF                         1946180
LOGOFF BY CLEANUP               754683
LOGON                             1026
```

It doesn't make sense that logons are less than 0.1% of logoffs.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you do a "group by" query and focus on username to see exactly what is doing all the logoffs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may depend on [whether you are using connection pooling](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1830073957439#15859893477812) or not.

Also, do you realize [LOGON and LOGOFF for a session are recorded in the same audit row](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/81704/237572/#msg_237572)? So here the LOGON is showing how many are still logged in right now.

Consider the following scenario.

```
SQL> select ACTION_NAME, username, count(*) from dba_audit_session group by action_name, username;
```

When you run this first time it shows LOGON 1.

Without logging off, try to connect as the same user as you have connected before.

```
SQL> select ACTION_NAME, username, count(*) from dba_audit_session group by action_name, username;
```

Now, it shows LOGON 1 and LOGOFF 1.

```
SQL> select ACTION_NAME, username, count(*) from dba_audit_session group by action_name, username;
```

Now, it shows LOGON 1 and LOGOFF 2.

Each time you are seeing the 1 currently logged in session as 'LOGON', and the (increasing) number of completed sessions as 'LOGOFF'.